# How to run a method at the beginning of an MVC3 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to populate an element from the Database, first thing when I compile/run my MVC3 application.
I have a static class and static method to populate the element. I just need to know how I could somehow call the method at the startup of my application.

Here's the code:

```
public static class Select_Brands
    {
        public static IQueryable<Brand> BrandsQ { get; set; }

        public static IQueryable<Brand> GetBrands()
        {
            using (Online_Store_DBEntities EFModel = new Online_Store_DBEntities())
            {
                BrandsQ = EFModel.Brands;
            }
            return BrandsQ;
        }
    }
```

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In every MVC Application you have a Global.asax like in an ASP.NET Application and you can run code in Application_Start() Method.

But you should think about where to persist the data and what you really use this for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in the `global.asax` file called `Application_Start` - sounds like this could be a candidate for what you want.